# Visual Studio can't attach to Unity "Operation could not be completed"

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

This was working last night. I've loaded up Unity today, made zero changes that could cause something like this to happen and it's just stopped working for no reason.

"Attach to Unity" doesn't work, "Attach to Unity and Play" doesn't work.

How do I fix this? There's no information on Google and zero helpful information in the error message.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio loses ability to attach to Unity, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337121/visual-studio-loses-ability-to-attach-to-unity-why)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and no closing, restarting VS or Unity would help. Then I found this post: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-operation-could-not-be-completed-unspecified-e-4/1654024
It mentions network interfaces for virtualization systems. I had a HyperV machine running in the background so I shut it down and restarted VS. The debugger connected immediately.

Comment: I have recurrent issues with debugging Unity 2021 from VS. This "Operation could not be completed" appeared recently and stopping HyperV services apparently fixed it after VS was restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Just disabled everything contains Hyper-V in this list and it worked.
[Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmJyR.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).