# Visual Studio 'Attach to Unity' button disappeared when I double clicked on editor console debug log line

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS2019 16.10.0 with Unity2020.3.0

Every time I double click on the Console window debug log line, the VS 'Attach to Unity' button will disappear from the toolbar and become a 'Start' button.

[image: Start]

I have to click 'Regenerating the project files' to make it back to normal.

[image: External Tool snapshot]

How do I fix this?

Comment: This seems to be a ["known" issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337121/visual-studio-loses-ability-to-attach-to-unity-why) - this might be the only solution.